# Chart returning aggregated values across 24-hour period

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have requirement to build bar chart in Apex 4.1 that would count all instances of action in 24 hours and present data grouped by hour.
Bar chart query is based on three fields.

```
Select '' link, to_char(created_on,HH) label, count(id) value from mytable1
where created_on like IN (SELECT LEVEL-1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24;)
```

Link is not required, label is going to be each hour so 00,01,02,03,04,..23 and value is going to be `count(id)` Table one has column called created_on which capture timestamp. I am capturing hours value by doing `to_char(created_on,HH)` However this query will result only occurrences that happened ( existed), so if there are no id say at 10 then there will be no results for that period of time. I need some sort of wrapping mechanism over that query which would count from 0 to 23.

Any help with building that query or directing me to functions I need greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not believe that this question should be put on hold. I DESCRIBED requirements of my query. My query was returning results, however not the one required. Answer provided by Ed Gibs solved my problem which proves that problem has been clearly explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will create a counter table from 1-24, and I'm pretty sure it works on 10g:

```
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24;
```

To get a counter table from 0-23 just subtract 1 from the `LEVEL`:

```
SELECT LEVEL-1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24;
```

Use the above as your "main" table and `LEFT JOIN` to your table:

```
SELECT
 whatever AS link,
 Ctr.HourValue AS label,
 COUNT(id) AS value
FROM
 (SELECT LEVEL-1 AS HourValue
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24) Ctr
LEFT JOIN mytable1 ON ctr.HourValue = TO_CHAR(mytable1.created_on, 'HH24')
WHERE <whatever>
GROUP BY whatever, Ctr.HourValue
```

Notes:

- You need to use the `HH24` format code because `HH` uses the 12-hour clock.
- You could also use the `EXTRACT` function for hours: `... ON ctr.HourValue = EXTRACT(HOUR FROM mytable1.created_on)`. I find this more readable, but that's subjective. There's no "best way" so use what you prefer - you're the one who'll be stuck maintaining the query :)

Comment: I accept this answer - Thanks Ed Gibbs. For some reason my SQL developer has still some issues with JOIN because it is not returning all values but I will tinker that.